# Examples of transitive and not negatively transitive binary relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Example of a binary relation that is transitive and not negatively transitive:

My try: $1\neq 2$ and $2\neq 1$ does not imply $1\neq 1$ Not neg transitive.

But if $1=2$ and $2=1$ then $1=1$ by transitivity.

Example of a binary relation that is negatively transitive but not transitive.

My try: Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dictionary letters" order is one.  Consider the following set with $5$ letters, say:

$$\{(a,c), (a,d), (a,e), (b,d), (b,e), (c,e)\}$$

In order for the coordinates to be in the set, the letter must come in earlier before any letter in the alphabet.

Comment: I don't understand how it's neg transitive.

Comment: I mean not neg transitive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What if you just take $\neq$ as your relation?  Why is this negatively transitive?

Comment: Oh I see. I made a mistake in changing the relation in one example.

Comment: You haven't made any mistakes as far as I can tell.  The point is that the relation defined by "$=$" is transitive, but not negatively transitive.  Likewise, the relation $\neq$ is negatively transitive, but not transitive.

Comment: So I just do the opposite for transitive and neg transitive example? Just switch the lines from example 1?

Comment: Pretty much. By that first line, $\neq$ is not transitive.  By that second line, $\neq$ is negatively transitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would be a good example:

Let X = {x,y,z} and the binary relation on X, R = {(x,y)} (that is, xRy),

This is transitive, since only two elements are related. However, it is NOT negatively transitive because  $\neg$zRy and $\neg$xRz but xRy!